# Arquivo sem extensão

Tags: c#, api

Tenho uma aplicação que faz o stream de um arquivo de áudio em uma pagina, porém ao tentar fazer o download de do arquivo o mesmo vem sem extensão.

Segue o código que uso :

```
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(string filename)
    {
        AudioSteam audio = new AudioSteam(filename);

       var response = Request.CreateResponse();
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var buffer = new byte[65536];

                using (var video = File.Open(audio._filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var length = (int)video.Length;
                    var bytesRead = 1;

                    while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));
                        await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        length -= bytesRead;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                outputStream.Close();
            }
        });

        return response;
    }
```

Segue a imagem do arquivo baixado na minha via minha pagina.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se pode ver o arquivo vem com o nome download e sem a extensão, como implemento para o que o mesmo tenha o nome original do arquivo e a extensão?

Comment: Tente: 
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "nome_do_meu_arquivo";
 return response;

Comment: @NetinhoSantos Nao funcionou !

Comment: response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");  
               response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "nome_do_meu_arquivo;  
               response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
Fonte: http://www.pashov.net/code/Download+large+files+with+Web+Api+as+a+relay

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145505/4713574

Comment: Deu certo Obrigado!